# Install object-recognition failed

Tags: ros, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run:

```
 lxz@lxz-F83VF:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-object-*
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Note, selecting 'ros-fuerte-object-manipulation' for regex 'ros-fuerte-object-*'
 Note, selecting 'ros-fuerte-object-recognition-capture' for regex      'ros-fuerte-object-*'
 Note, selecting 'ros-fuerte-object-recognition-core' for regex      'ros-fuerte-object-*'
 Note, selecting 'ros-fuerte-object-recognition-msgs' for regex      'ros-fuerte-object-*'
 Note, selecting 'ros-fuerte-object-recognition-linemod' for regex      'ros-fuerte-object-*'
 Note, selecting 'ros-fuerte-object-recognition-reconstruction' for regex      'ros-fuerte-object-*'
 Note, selecting 'ros-fuerte-object-recognition-tod' for regex      'ros-fuerte-object-*'
 Note, selecting 'ros-fuerte-object-recognition-transparent-objects' for regex      'ros-fuerte-object-*'
 ros-fuerte-object-manipulation is already the newest version.
 ros-fuerte-object-recognition-core is already the newest version.
 ros-fuerte-object-recognition-linemod is already the newest version.
 ros-fuerte-object-recognition-msgs is already the newest version.
 ros-fuerte-object-recognition-tod is already the newest version.
 ros-fuerte-object-recognition-transparent-objects is already the newest      version.
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
   ros-fuerte-object-recognition-capture
   ros-fuerte-object-recognition-reconstruction
 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 369 not upgraded.
 725 not fully installed or removed.
 Need to get 0 B/480 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 1929 kB of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
 perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
 perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "zh_TW:zh",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_MESSAGE = "en_US.UTF8",
    LANG = "en_US"
     are supported and installed on your system.
 perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
 locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
 locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
 locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
 (Reading database ... 250918 files and directories currently installed.)
 Unpacking ros-fuerte-object-recognition-capture      (from .../ros-fuerte-object-recognition-capture_0.2.7-1oneiric-20120512-0309-+0000     _amd64.deb) ...
 dpkg: error processing      /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-fuerte-object-recognition-capture_0.2.7-1oneiric-20120     512-0309-+0000_amd64.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/roscompat.py', which is also in      package ros-fuerte-object-recognition-core 0.3.1-0oneiric-20120512-0157-+0000
 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
 Unpacking ros-fuerte-object-recognition-reconstruction      (from .../ros-fuerte-object-recognition-reconstruction_0.2.4-0oneiric-20120512-0316     -+0000_amd64.deb) ...
 dpkg: error processing      /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-fuerte-object-recognition-reconstruction_0.2.4-0oneiric     -20120512-0316-+0000_amd64.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/roscompat.py', which is also in      package ros-fuerte-object-recognition-core 0.3.1-0oneiric-20120512-0157-+0000
 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
 Errors were encountered while processing:
       /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-fuerte-object-recognition-capture_0.2.7-1oneiric-20120     512-0309-+0000_amd64.deb
       /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-fuerte-object-recognition-reconstruction_0.2.4-0oneiric     -20120512-0316-+0000_amd64.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
 lxz@lxz-F83VF:~$
```

How to solve it?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34552/install-object-recognition-failed/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixes have been released but due to work on the new build system, they have not been pushed yet sorry. For future bugs, please file a bug report on http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/ ,thx

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0